# Looking for FOTA to update firmware with wi-fi over internet (ESP32)

Tags: esp32, ota

I have tried ArduinoOTA and AsyncElegantOTA and they work, but only when you are in the same wi-fi as ESP32.

I need to update ESP32 firmware "remotely" meaning when I'm not in the same local wi-fi network as ESP32.

Has this been done yet for Arduino?

Comment: the HTTPUpdate library bundled with the esp32 Arduino core